# how to change an integer value in dataframe by its location on a tuple?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given this tuple `my_tuple = ("bob", "joe", "frank")` and given this dataframe `df`:

```
    col_1   col_2
0     abc       2
1     cba       1
2     bca       0
```

Is there a way to replace the values of `col_2` using this `int` number as index and finding it in `my_tuple`, without needing to use `df.iterrows()` ?

The result should be:

```
    col_1   col_2
0     abc   frank
1     cba     joe
2     bca     bob
```

Comment: `df['col_2'] = df['col_2'] .apply(lambda x: my_typle[x])` make sure your tuple does not create out of index error

Answer (score 3):

You can `map` with a `dict` using enumerate. This is fast and avoids any `IndexErrors` (will return `NaN` for indices out of bounds).

```
df['new_col'] = df['col_2'].map(dict(enumerate(my_tuple)))

  col_1  col_2 new_col
0   abc      2   frank
1   cba      1     joe
2   bca      0     bob
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pd.merge` like this:

```
df = (df.merge(pd.DataFrame(my_tuple), right_index=True,
               left_on='col2', how='left')
        .drop('col2', axis = 1).reset_index(drop = True))
```

Your result will be something like:

```
  col1      0
0  abc  frank
1  cba    joe
2  bca    bob
```

Then you can simply rename the columns with:

```
df.columns = ['col1', 'col2']
```